# If i've array nums = [1,2,3] and if i change it to a set ; nums = new Set(nums). Is it considered as extra space?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, space-complexity

Initially, we've an array nums of integers as

nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

If I change that same array into a different data structure let's say an object, map, or a set using the same variable

nums = new Set(nums)

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4]  //O(n) space
nums = new Set(nums); // is this the extra space or not?
```

Is it considered extra space? or is it constant space?

Thanks

Comment: It is an extra allocation, but space is still linear. In estimating Big O we ignore constants. So, 2n = n.

Comment: It depends on what you're counting. If you're using f(n) space total, and the input uses g(n) space, you can think of the "extra" space as additive, so the total new space is `f(n)-g(n)`, in which case your algorithm uses O(n) extra space. You can also think of it as a growth factor `f(n)/g(n)`, in which case your extra space is O(1). The former seems more natural to me - you're allocating a linear amount of space for your set, so O(n) space seems like the way to express that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it considered extra space? or is it constant space?

The numbers in the input array are *copied* into the set. So it is to be considered extra space (auxiliary space), and it is not constant. It is O(n).